# Why a nested IIFE is not creating closure?

Tags: javascript

I'm reading [this resource](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20%26%20closures/ch5.md) trying to understand how closure works in Javascript.

I understood that every time a function is called outside its normal lexical scope, it creates closure, being able to access the enclosing function variables and using them to store state.

This works in `my_module.incrCounter();` below (which keeps increasing the counter), but why it doesn't work in `my_module.incrLocalCounter();`, which keeps returning 1 every time?

Shouldn't the IIFE inside `incrLocalCounter` create closure over `local_counter` ?

```
var my_module = (function tlModule(){

  var counter = 0;

  function incrCounter(){

    counter++
    console.log(counter);

  };



  function incrLocalCounter(){

    var local_counter = 0;

    (function () {
      local_counter++
      console.log(local_counter)
    })();

  };

  return {

    incrCounter: incrCounter,
    incrLocalCounter: incrLocalCounter

  }

})();
```

Comment: *every time a function is called outside its normal lexical scope, it creates closure* — that's not really correct. A function call essentially *always* creates a closure, though in many cases the closure is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Your "nested" IIFE logs 1 every time because the variable that is incremented is always initialized to 0 before the IIFE runs. That is, inside that nested function, `local_counter` always starts off at 0.

If you move the `var` declaration for `local_counter` to outside `incrLocalCounter()`, then you'll see it increment. Alternatively, you could have `incrLocalCounter()` return a *function* and have that be the property value you return:

```
function incrLocalCounter(){

  var local_counter = 0;

  return function () {
    local_counter++
    console.log(local_counter)
  };

};

return {

  incrCounter: incrCounter,
  incrLocalCounter: incrLocalCounter() // <-- call the function

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Shouldn't the IIFE inside `incrLocalCounter` create closure over `local_counter` ?

It does. `local_counter` is at `0` at that time. Then it increments it from `0` to `1` by executing the IIFE. Then it returns `1`. And it does this same sequence (including setting `local_counter` to `0`) each time you call `incrLocalCounter`. The difference is not that `incrLocalCounter` has an IIFE; the difference is whether the variable being incremented is being reset within the function or not.